# How to view Epics in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have just started using Team Foundation Server (version 15). I thought I could use Epics to organize features and other work elements but when I create an Epic I don't see where it is and can't see how to associate a Feature to it. Am I misunderstanding the use of Epics? I have been given a single project called Workflow under which I need to manage multiple clients. Epics seems a good container for a client level object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From your team's backlog page, click the gear icon (gear icon) to open the common configuration team settings.
2. Click the Backlogs tab and check the boxes of those backlog levels you want your team to manage.

**Source :** [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/select-backlog-navigation-levels?view=vsts)

Comment: In short: Work > Click Settings Icon (the wheel) > General > Backlogs > Check Epics